# XOR is not giving me the numbers 0 or 1

Tags: java, char, integer, bit-manipulation, xor

My current inputs are "11" and "1"
My variable longer is for "11" and carry is "1".

```
int carry = 1;
String longer = "11";
System.out.println(carry);  ---> 1
System.out.println(longer.charAt(1)); ---> 1
System.out.println(carry ^ longer.charAt(i)); ---> 48
```

Why does `carry = 1` and `longer.charAt(i) = 1` but when I XOR the two, I get 48, which isn't even a binary number?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `1` and `'1'`?

Comment: You're printing out ints, though.  If you wanted the binary representation you would need to use `Integer.toBinaryString` instead.

Comment: try this to see what's wrong: `System.out.println((int) '1');`

Comment: Sorry, carry is an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char 1`'s binary is `00000000 00110001`,

`int 1`'s binary is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`

when you `char 1 ^ int 1`, `char 1` will be promoted to `int` by adding 16 zeros at the begin of `00000000 00110001`, so you are actually doing:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00110001 
^
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

the result is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00110000, in dicimal 48
```

---

You can parse `char 1` to `int 1` before `^`:

```
int carry = 1;
String longer = "11";
int longerInt = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(longer.charAt(1)));

System.out.println(carry ^ longer.charAt(1)); //48
System.out.println(carry ^ longerInt); // 0
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Do you know why `System.out.println(shorter.charAt(0) ^ longer.charAt(0) ^ 1  == 1)` works even without parsing?; (shorter.charAt(0) == '1' && longer.charAt(0) == '1')

Comment: Because both are chars, `00000000 00110001` ^ `00000000 00110001` ---> 0